# How do I place a specific JSON output entry in a variable based on another conditional output?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to place a certain UUID into a variable based on another ID.

When I perform a GET call I get a JSON output with two records.

Based on the "name" (webapp-vs-sitea and webapp-vs-siteb) I want to place the UUID in a variable so that I can use it later.

**webapp-vs-sitea has this uuid: virtualservice-c1016a0b-4b27-4faa-944a-87a31982c46d**

**webapp-vs-siteb has this uuid: virtualservice-15c00a2f-3184-4785-b327-ca83ea64efaf**

This UUID can be different every time, but the name will be the same.
So based on the word (name), I want to place the UUID in a variable.

I have no clue how to do this, can someone assist me with this?

I have used the following API call:

```
https://avi-01a/api/virtualservice/
```

This produces the following JSON output:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "results": [
        {
            "_last_modified": "1686347917809336",
            "active_standby_se_tag": "ACTIVE_STANDBY_SE_1",
            "advertise_down_vs": false,
            "allow_invalid_client_cert": false,
            "analytics_policy": {
                "all_headers": false,
                "client_insights": "NO_INSIGHTS",
                "full_client_logs": {
                    "duration": 0,
                    "enabled": false,
                    "throttle": 10
                },
                "metrics_realtime_update": {
                    "duration": 30,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                "significant_log_throttle": 10,
                "udf_log_throttle": 10
            },
            "analytics_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/analyticsprofile/analyticsprofile-d89949d8-78df-4546-8f7b-de6b35095cfd",
            "application_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/applicationprofile/applicationprofile-3fa22338-eb22-44d2-86bd-ebbee266e68c",
            "bulk_sync_kvcache": false,
            "close_client_conn_on_config_update": false,
            "cloud_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/cloud/cloud-2b660f81-253f-4f16-802a-f7723eb6d719",
            "cloud_type": "CLOUD_NSXT",
            "delay_fairness": false,
            "east_west_placement": false,
            "enable_autogw": true,
            "enabled": true,
            "error_page_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/errorpageprofile/errorpageprofile-a3ae492f-cfea-425c-a772-8b3e9849c2c0",
            "flow_dist": "LOAD_AWARE",
            "flow_label_type": "NO_LABEL",
            "http_policies": [
                {
                    "http_policy_set_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/httppolicyset/httppolicyset-3e94f75e-a0d5-4a1f-8e1b-25c54a538227",
                    "index": 11
                }
            ],
            "ign_pool_net_reach": false,
            "limit_doser": false,
            "marked_for_delete": false,
            "max_cps_per_client": 0,
            "name": "webapp-vs-sitea",
            "network_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/networkprofile/networkprofile-da898b72-97a6-4701-9ff6-ea2b2a98b4b1",
            "network_security_policy_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/networksecuritypolicy/networksecuritypolicy-f9962830-f1f4-41e2-a120-ff4949e3e79a",
            "pool_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/pool/pool-18ba4616-6d56-473f-8cfa-3c0c4d838079",
            "redis_db": 12,
            "redis_port": 5022,
            "remove_listening_port_on_vs_down": false,
            "scaleout_ecmp": true,
            "se_group_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/serviceenginegroup/serviceenginegroup-07876727-5f0f-4ef6-bf0b-e27c9dacf7bc",
            "self_se_election": false,
            "services": [
                {
                    "enable_http2": false,
                    "enable_ssl": true,
                    "port": 443,
                    "port_range_end": 443
                }
            ],
            "ssl_key_and_certificate_refs": [
                "https://avi-01a/api/sslkeyandcertificate/sslkeyandcertificate-f17b210d-2109-4c49-b3a6-86e0d46cd1e0"
            ],
            "ssl_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/sslprofile/sslprofile-c2cc91c0-75a4-49e8-ac45-507f0674941d",
            "ssl_sess_cache_avg_size": 1024,
            "tenant_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/tenant/admin",
            "tls_ticket_key": [
                {
                    "aes_key": "VoEWEZpMZ4h6zxKUB2As+g==",
                    "hmac_key": "BWBjec3HeDddsWWuXzy6UA==",
                    "name": "2180807e-775c-42a1-beff-609148492920"
                },
                {
                    "aes_key": "em3Ixrg9wTgE0CsJ2M7vBw==",
                    "hmac_key": "UQm7DKWgMYonwbH+TIRLUQ==",
                    "name": "d76775df-f182-4c7c-9ee8-5dfb5b7d5911"
                },
                {
                    "aes_key": "8SofzqYU97A+hdBaZKqEmg==",
                    "hmac_key": "aDCOJ6MvVGaAsZ7L8DiwMQ==",
                    "name": "c80a379c-d6f7-4cb9-8553-cd9a84b090a1"
                }
            ],
            "traffic_enabled": true,
            "type": "VS_TYPE_NORMAL",
            "url": "https://avi-01a/api/virtualservice/virtualservice-c1016a0b-4b27-4faa-944a-87a31982c46d",
            "use_bridge_ip_as_vip": false,
            "use_vip_as_snat": false,
            "uuid": "virtualservice-c1016a0b-4b27-4faa-944a-87a31982c46d",
            "version": 103,
            "vip_runtime": [
                {
                    "first_se_assigned_time": {
                        "secs": 1686347928,
                        "usecs": 191199
                    },
                    "num_additional_se": 0,
                    "requested_resource": {
                        "num_se": 1,
                        "num_standby_se": 0
                    },
                    "se_list": [
                        {
                            "active_on_cloud": true,
                            "active_on_se": true,
                            "admin_down_requested": false,
                            "attach_ip_in_progress": false,
                            "cloud_programming_done": true,
                            "cloud_programming_status": "Virtual Service IP is reachable in the Cloud",
                            "delete_in_progress": false,
                            "detach_ip_in_progress": false,
                            "incarnation": "2023-06-09 21:58:48.192169",
                            "is_portchannel": false,
                            "is_primary": true,
                            "is_standby": false,
                            "memory": 1983,
                            "mgmt_ip": {
                                "addr": "172.16.90.13",
                                "type": "V4"
                            },
                            "scaleout_in_progress": false,
                            "se_programming_done": true,
                            "se_ready_in_progress": false,
                            "se_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/serviceengine/se-005056a14f28",
                            "sec_idx": 0,
                            "vcpus": 1,
                            "vip6_subnet_mask": 128,
                            "vip_intf_list": [
                                {
                                    "is_portchannel": false,
                                    "vip_intf_ip": {
                                        "addr": "172.16.100.51",
                                        "type": "V4"
                                    },
                                    "vip_intf_mac": "00:50:56:a1:18:55",
                                    "vlan_id": 0
                                }
                            ],
                            "vip_intf_mac": "00:50:56:a1:18:55",
                            "vip_subnet_mask": 32,
                            "vlan_id": 0,
                            "vnic": [
                                {
                                    "mac": "00:50:56:a1:18:55",
                                    "type": "VNIC_TYPE_FE"
                                },
                                {
                                    "mac": "00:50:56:a1:18:55",
                                    "type": "VNIC_TYPE_BE"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "vip_id": "1"
                }
            ],
            "vrf_context_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/vrfcontext/vrfcontext-f99519ca-5105-4e3c-9fde-06b43eb2bc74",
            "vsvip_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/vsvip/vsvip-04ad3285-9563-4d1f-be7b-89680087a9eb",
            "weight": 1
        },
        {
            "_last_modified": "1682947981023420",
            "active_standby_se_tag": "ACTIVE_STANDBY_SE_1",
            "advertise_down_vs": false,
            "allow_invalid_client_cert": false,
            "analytics_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/analyticsprofile/analyticsprofile-d89949d8-78df-4546-8f7b-de6b35095cfd",
            "application_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/applicationprofile/applicationprofile-3fa22338-eb22-44d2-86bd-ebbee266e68c",
            "bulk_sync_kvcache": false,
            "close_client_conn_on_config_update": false,
            "cloud_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/cloud/cloud-909f3518-0cc2-4fed-b444-7352d1a064ad",
            "cloud_type": "CLOUD_NSXT",
            "delay_fairness": false,
            "east_west_placement": false,
            "enable_autogw": true,
            "enabled": true,
            "error_page_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/errorpageprofile/errorpageprofile-a3ae492f-cfea-425c-a772-8b3e9849c2c0",
            "flow_dist": "LOAD_AWARE",
            "flow_label_type": "NO_LABEL",
            "ign_pool_net_reach": false,
            "limit_doser": false,
            "marked_for_delete": false,
            "max_cps_per_client": 0,
            "name": "webapp-vs-siteb",
            "network_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/networkprofile/networkprofile-da898b72-97a6-4701-9ff6-ea2b2a98b4b1",
            "pool_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/pool/pool-2b734a61-777c-411b-aaad-60ed91defd25",
            "redis_db": 11,
            "redis_port": 5028,
            "remove_listening_port_on_vs_down": false,
            "scaleout_ecmp": true,
            "se_group_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/serviceenginegroup/serviceenginegroup-5df7babe-7d43-4ff1-9701-785b09cc1f7b",
            "self_se_election": false,
            "services": [
                {
                    "enable_http2": false,
                    "enable_ssl": true,
                    "port": 443,
                    "port_range_end": 443
                }
            ],
            "ssl_key_and_certificate_refs": [
                "https://avi-01a/api/sslkeyandcertificate/sslkeyandcertificate-f17b210d-2109-4c49-b3a6-86e0d46cd1e0"
            ],
            "ssl_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/sslprofile/sslprofile-371fd0ef-d8df-4841-8283-47305cb8014e",
            "ssl_sess_cache_avg_size": 1024,
            "tenant_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/tenant/admin",
            "tls_ticket_key": [
                {
                    "aes_key": "qv8CJ706XYuKJnOkaXblYg==",
                    "hmac_key": "8IWIL5/XijDGih1uqADqJg==",
                    "name": "70f8d7a9-ebc9-44c9-8a3d-675d78484ec9"
                },
                {
                    "aes_key": "9vO6f6F0CnYxtPv2A1NUQQ==",
                    "hmac_key": "LYdU0Lm0BBRcgJG8JXniag==",
                    "name": "8ba26c95-a0eb-4d6a-b7fe-5336db1036a5"
                },
                {
                    "aes_key": "H5yJItSIwcEn39SA24weRA==",
                    "hmac_key": "5LdrUzCLP3VONrK4l7IRLg==",
                    "name": "bde57feb-ebeb-4992-aef0-b00a9f5d228b"
                }
            ],
            "traffic_enabled": true,
            "type": "VS_TYPE_NORMAL",
            "url": "https://avi-01a/api/virtualservice/virtualservice-15c00a2f-3184-4785-b327-ca83ea64efaf",
            "use_bridge_ip_as_vip": false,
            "use_vip_as_snat": false,
            "uuid": "virtualservice-15c00a2f-3184-4785-b327-ca83ea64efaf",
            "version": 72,
            "vip_runtime": [
                {
                    "first_se_assigned_time": {
                        "secs": 1686347797,
                        "usecs": 666539
                    },
                    "num_additional_se": 0,
                    "requested_resource": {
                        "num_se": 1,
                        "num_standby_se": 0
                    },
                    "se_list": [
                        {
                            "active_on_cloud": true,
                            "active_on_se": true,
                            "admin_down_requested": false,
                            "attach_ip_in_progress": false,
                            "cloud_programming_done": true,
                            "cloud_programming_status": "Virtual Service IP is reachable in the Cloud",
                            "delete_in_progress": false,
                            "detach_ip_in_progress": false,
                            "incarnation": "2023-06-09 21:56:37.666826",
                            "is_portchannel": false,
                            "is_primary": true,
                            "is_standby": false,
                            "memory": 1983,
                            "mgmt_ip": {
                                "addr": "172.26.90.12",
                                "type": "V4"
                            },
                            "scaleout_in_progress": false,
                            "se_programming_done": true,
                            "se_ready_in_progress": false,
                            "se_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/serviceengine/se-0050568af8e9",
                            "sec_idx": 0,
                            "vcpus": 1,
                            "vip6_subnet_mask": 128,
                            "vip_intf_list": [
                                {
                                    "is_portchannel": false,
                                    "vip_intf_ip": {
                                        "addr": "172.26.100.52",
                                        "type": "V4"
                                    },
                                    "vip_intf_mac": "00:50:56:8a:69:be",
                                    "vlan_id": 0
                                }
                            ],
                            "vip_intf_mac": "00:50:56:8a:69:be",
                            "vip_subnet_mask": 32,
                            "vlan_id": 0,
                            "vnic": [
                                {
                                    "mac": "00:50:56:8a:69:be",
                                    "type": "VNIC_TYPE_FE"
                                },
                                {
                                    "mac": "00:50:56:8a:69:be",
                                    "type": "VNIC_TYPE_BE"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "vip_id": "0"
                }
            ],
            "vrf_context_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/vrfcontext/vrfcontext-bca8bebe-ac97-415c-8a91-2ae460991cf2",
            "vsvip_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/vsvip/vsvip-188c0926-859f-43c2-a815-ae1f99fc8eb6",
            "weight": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

My PowerShell Script so far:

```
Function Resolve-Lab-7.7
{
    
    Process {

    #Connection to AVI Controller
    $base64CredsAVI = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('admin:<password>'))
    $headerAVI = @{Authorization = "Basic $base64CredsAVI"}
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls13
    $uriAvi = "https://avi-01a"

    #Get AVI Virtual Servers
    $resultsAviVS = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$uriAvi/api/virtualservice" -Headers $headerAVI

    #Create a Hashtable to hold the testables
    $testingHash = [hashtable]::new()

    #Parse return and create an object from the results
    $aviItems = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $resultsAviVS.Content -Depth 100 -AsHashtable

   #Find the AVI Virtual Services and store it in the testing hashtable
   foreach ($avi in $aviItems.results)
   {
       If ($avi.name -like "webapp-vs-sitea")
       {
           Write-Host "webapp-vs-sitea VS found in AVI Controller" -ForegroundColor Green
           Write-Host "The UUID that belongs to webapp-vs-sitea is: $uuidSiteA"
       }
   }
   If ($null -eq $testingHash.AVI)
   {
       Write-Host "webapp-vs-sitea VS not found in AVI Controller" -ForegroundColor Red
   }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code snippet (with hard-coded `$resultsAviVS`) could help:

```
#Requires -Version 6.0
Function Resolve-Lab-76540800 {

# $resultsAviVS hardcoded:
$resultsAviVS = @{
Question = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76540800/'
Content = @'
{
    "count": 2,
    "results": [
        {
            "_last_modified": "1686347917809336",
            "active_standby_se_tag": "ACTIVE_STANDBY_SE_1",
            "advertise_down_vs": false,
            "allow_invalid_client_cert": false,
            "analytics_policy": {
                "all_headers": false,
                "client_insights": "NO_INSIGHTS",
                "full_client_logs": {
                    "duration": 0,
                    "enabled": false,
                    "throttle": 10
                },
                "metrics_realtime_update": {
                    "duration": 30,
                    "enabled": false
                },
                "significant_log_throttle": 10,
                "udf_log_throttle": 10
            },
            "analytics_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/analyticsprofile/analyticsprofile-d89949d8-78df-4546-8f7b-de6b35095cfd",
            "application_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/applicationprofile/applicationprofile-3fa22338-eb22-44d2-86bd-ebbee266e68c",
            "bulk_sync_kvcache": false,
            "close_client_conn_on_config_update": false,
            "cloud_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/cloud/cloud-2b660f81-253f-4f16-802a-f7723eb6d719",
            "cloud_type": "CLOUD_NSXT",
            "delay_fairness": false,
            "east_west_placement": false,
            "enable_autogw": true,
            "enabled": true,
            "error_page_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/errorpageprofile/errorpageprofile-a3ae492f-cfea-425c-a772-8b3e9849c2c0",
            "flow_dist": "LOAD_AWARE",
            "flow_label_type": "NO_LABEL",
            "http_policies": [
                {
                    "http_policy_set_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/httppolicyset/httppolicyset-3e94f75e-a0d5-4a1f-8e1b-25c54a538227",
                    "index": 11
                }
            ],
            "ign_pool_net_reach": false,
            "limit_doser": false,
            "marked_for_delete": false,
            "max_cps_per_client": 0,
            "name": "webapp-vs-sitea",
            "network_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/networkprofile/networkprofile-da898b72-97a6-4701-9ff6-ea2b2a98b4b1",
            "network_security_policy_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/networksecuritypolicy/networksecuritypolicy-f9962830-f1f4-41e2-a120-ff4949e3e79a",
            "pool_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/pool/pool-18ba4616-6d56-473f-8cfa-3c0c4d838079",
            "redis_db": 12,
            "redis_port": 5022,
            "remove_listening_port_on_vs_down": false,
            "scaleout_ecmp": true,
            "se_group_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/serviceenginegroup/serviceenginegroup-07876727-5f0f-4ef6-bf0b-e27c9dacf7bc",
            "self_se_election": false,
            "services": [
                {
                    "enable_http2": false,
                    "enable_ssl": true,
                    "port": 443,
                    "port_range_end": 443
                }
            ],
            "ssl_key_and_certificate_refs": [
                "https://avi-01a/api/sslkeyandcertificate/sslkeyandcertificate-f17b210d-2109-4c49-b3a6-86e0d46cd1e0"
            ],
            "ssl_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/sslprofile/sslprofile-c2cc91c0-75a4-49e8-ac45-507f0674941d",
            "ssl_sess_cache_avg_size": 1024,
            "tenant_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/tenant/admin",
            "tls_ticket_key": [
                {
                    "aes_key": "VoEWEZpMZ4h6zxKUB2As+g==",
                    "hmac_key": "BWBjec3HeDddsWWuXzy6UA==",
                    "name": "2180807e-775c-42a1-beff-609148492920"
                },
                {
                    "aes_key": "em3Ixrg9wTgE0CsJ2M7vBw==",
                    "hmac_key": "UQm7DKWgMYonwbH+TIRLUQ==",
                    "name": "d76775df-f182-4c7c-9ee8-5dfb5b7d5911"
                },
                {
                    "aes_key": "8SofzqYU97A+hdBaZKqEmg==",
                    "hmac_key": "aDCOJ6MvVGaAsZ7L8DiwMQ==",
                    "name": "c80a379c-d6f7-4cb9-8553-cd9a84b090a1"
                }
            ],
            "traffic_enabled": true,
            "type": "VS_TYPE_NORMAL",
            "url": "https://avi-01a/api/virtualservice/virtualservice-c1016a0b-4b27-4faa-944a-87a31982c46d",
            "use_bridge_ip_as_vip": false,
            "use_vip_as_snat": false,
            "uuid": "virtualservice-c1016a0b-4b27-4faa-944a-87a31982c46d",
            "version": 103,
            "vip_runtime": [
                {
                    "first_se_assigned_time": {
                        "secs": 1686347928,
                        "usecs": 191199
                    },
                    "num_additional_se": 0,
                    "requested_resource": {
                        "num_se": 1,
                        "num_standby_se": 0
                    },
                    "se_list": [
                        {
                            "active_on_cloud": true,
                            "active_on_se": true,
                            "admin_down_requested": false,
                            "attach_ip_in_progress": false,
                            "cloud_programming_done": true,
                            "cloud_programming_status": "Virtual Service IP is reachable in the Cloud",
                            "delete_in_progress": false,
                            "detach_ip_in_progress": false,
                            "incarnation": "2023-06-09 21:58:48.192169",
                            "is_portchannel": false,
                            "is_primary": true,
                            "is_standby": false,
                            "memory": 1983,
                            "mgmt_ip": {
                                "addr": "172.16.90.13",
                                "type": "V4"
                            },
                            "scaleout_in_progress": false,
                            "se_programming_done": true,
                            "se_ready_in_progress": false,
                            "se_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/serviceengine/se-005056a14f28",
                            "sec_idx": 0,
                            "vcpus": 1,
                            "vip6_subnet_mask": 128,
                            "vip_intf_list": [
                                {
                                    "is_portchannel": false,
                                    "vip_intf_ip": {
                                        "addr": "172.16.100.51",
                                        "type": "V4"
                                    },
                                    "vip_intf_mac": "00:50:56:a1:18:55",
                                    "vlan_id": 0
                                }
                            ],
                            "vip_intf_mac": "00:50:56:a1:18:55",
                            "vip_subnet_mask": 32,
                            "vlan_id": 0,
                            "vnic": [
                                {
                                    "mac": "00:50:56:a1:18:55",
                                    "type": "VNIC_TYPE_FE"
                                },
                                {
                                    "mac": "00:50:56:a1:18:55",
                                    "type": "VNIC_TYPE_BE"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "vip_id": "1"
                }
            ],
            "vrf_context_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/vrfcontext/vrfcontext-f99519ca-5105-4e3c-9fde-06b43eb2bc74",
            "vsvip_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/vsvip/vsvip-04ad3285-9563-4d1f-be7b-89680087a9eb",
            "weight": 1
        },
        {
            "_last_modified": "1682947981023420",
            "active_standby_se_tag": "ACTIVE_STANDBY_SE_1",
            "advertise_down_vs": false,
            "allow_invalid_client_cert": false,
            "analytics_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/analyticsprofile/analyticsprofile-d89949d8-78df-4546-8f7b-de6b35095cfd",
            "application_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/applicationprofile/applicationprofile-3fa22338-eb22-44d2-86bd-ebbee266e68c",
            "bulk_sync_kvcache": false,
            "close_client_conn_on_config_update": false,
            "cloud_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/cloud/cloud-909f3518-0cc2-4fed-b444-7352d1a064ad",
            "cloud_type": "CLOUD_NSXT",
            "delay_fairness": false,
            "east_west_placement": false,
            "enable_autogw": true,
            "enabled": true,
            "error_page_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/errorpageprofile/errorpageprofile-a3ae492f-cfea-425c-a772-8b3e9849c2c0",
            "flow_dist": "LOAD_AWARE",
            "flow_label_type": "NO_LABEL",
            "ign_pool_net_reach": false,
            "limit_doser": false,
            "marked_for_delete": false,
            "max_cps_per_client": 0,
            "name": "webapp-vs-siteb",
            "network_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/networkprofile/networkprofile-da898b72-97a6-4701-9ff6-ea2b2a98b4b1",
            "pool_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/pool/pool-2b734a61-777c-411b-aaad-60ed91defd25",
            "redis_db": 11,
            "redis_port": 5028,
            "remove_listening_port_on_vs_down": false,
            "scaleout_ecmp": true,
            "se_group_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/serviceenginegroup/serviceenginegroup-5df7babe-7d43-4ff1-9701-785b09cc1f7b",
            "self_se_election": false,
            "services": [
                {
                    "enable_http2": false,
                    "enable_ssl": true,
                    "port": 443,
                    "port_range_end": 443
                }
            ],
            "ssl_key_and_certificate_refs": [
                "https://avi-01a/api/sslkeyandcertificate/sslkeyandcertificate-f17b210d-2109-4c49-b3a6-86e0d46cd1e0"
            ],
            "ssl_profile_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/sslprofile/sslprofile-371fd0ef-d8df-4841-8283-47305cb8014e",
            "ssl_sess_cache_avg_size": 1024,
            "tenant_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/tenant/admin",
            "tls_ticket_key": [
                {
                    "aes_key": "qv8CJ706XYuKJnOkaXblYg==",
                    "hmac_key": "8IWIL5/XijDGih1uqADqJg==",
                    "name": "70f8d7a9-ebc9-44c9-8a3d-675d78484ec9"
                },
                {
                    "aes_key": "9vO6f6F0CnYxtPv2A1NUQQ==",
                    "hmac_key": "LYdU0Lm0BBRcgJG8JXniag==",
                    "name": "8ba26c95-a0eb-4d6a-b7fe-5336db1036a5"
                },
                {
                    "aes_key": "H5yJItSIwcEn39SA24weRA==",
                    "hmac_key": "5LdrUzCLP3VONrK4l7IRLg==",
                    "name": "bde57feb-ebeb-4992-aef0-b00a9f5d228b"
                }
            ],
            "traffic_enabled": true,
            "type": "VS_TYPE_NORMAL",
            "url": "https://avi-01a/api/virtualservice/virtualservice-15c00a2f-3184-4785-b327-ca83ea64efaf",
            "use_bridge_ip_as_vip": false,
            "use_vip_as_snat": false,
            "uuid": "virtualservice-15c00a2f-3184-4785-b327-ca83ea64efaf",
            "version": 72,
            "vip_runtime": [
                {
                    "first_se_assigned_time": {
                        "secs": 1686347797,
                        "usecs": 666539
                    },
                    "num_additional_se": 0,
                    "requested_resource": {
                        "num_se": 1,
                        "num_standby_se": 0
                    },
                    "se_list": [
                        {
                            "active_on_cloud": true,
                            "active_on_se": true,
                            "admin_down_requested": false,
                            "attach_ip_in_progress": false,
                            "cloud_programming_done": true,
                            "cloud_programming_status": "Virtual Service IP is reachable in the Cloud",
                            "delete_in_progress": false,
                            "detach_ip_in_progress": false,
                            "incarnation": "2023-06-09 21:56:37.666826",
                            "is_portchannel": false,
                            "is_primary": true,
                            "is_standby": false,
                            "memory": 1983,
                            "mgmt_ip": {
                                "addr": "172.26.90.12",
                                "type": "V4"
                            },
                            "scaleout_in_progress": false,
                            "se_programming_done": true,
                            "se_ready_in_progress": false,
                            "se_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/serviceengine/se-0050568af8e9",
                            "sec_idx": 0,
                            "vcpus": 1,
                            "vip6_subnet_mask": 128,
                            "vip_intf_list": [
                                {
                                    "is_portchannel": false,
                                    "vip_intf_ip": {
                                        "addr": "172.26.100.52",
                                        "type": "V4"
                                    },
                                    "vip_intf_mac": "00:50:56:8a:69:be",
                                    "vlan_id": 0
                                }
                            ],
                            "vip_intf_mac": "00:50:56:8a:69:be",
                            "vip_subnet_mask": 32,
                            "vlan_id": 0,
                            "vnic": [
                                {
                                    "mac": "00:50:56:8a:69:be",
                                    "type": "VNIC_TYPE_FE"
                                },
                                {
                                    "mac": "00:50:56:8a:69:be",
                                    "type": "VNIC_TYPE_BE"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "vip_id": "0"
                }
            ],
            "vrf_context_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/vrfcontext/vrfcontext-bca8bebe-ac97-415c-8a91-2ae460991cf2",
            "vsvip_ref": "https://avi-01a/api/vsvip/vsvip-188c0926-859f-43c2-a815-ae1f99fc8eb6",
            "weight": 1
        }
    ]
}
'@
}

    $aviItems = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $resultsAviVS.Content -Depth 100 -AsHashtable

    #Create a Hashtable to hold the testables
    $testingHash = [hashtable]::new()

    foreach ($avi in $aviItems.results) {
        Write-Host "$($avi.name) -> $($avi.uuid)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        $testingHash.Add($avi.name, $avi.uuid)
    }

    $testingHash
}
```

Apply it as follows (dot source the script so that the `Resolve-Lab-76540800` function is added to the current scope, overriding existing one):

```
. D:\PShell\SO\76540800.ps1
$myHash = Resolve-Lab-76540800
```

Then, use `$myHash` as follows:

```
$myHash.'webapp-vs-sitea'  # virtualservice-c1016a0b-4b27-4faa-944a-87a31982c46d
# or
$myHash['webapp-vs-siteb'] # virtualservice-15c00a2f-3184-4785-b327-ca83ea64efaf
```

Comment: Thank you for this with this example I got it to work.